# Как распарсить строку с объектом JSON?

Tags: json, java, android, синтаксический-анализ

Есть код парсинга массива, сам недавно делал:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (status == 200) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(data);

    for (int i=0; i<jsonarr.length();i++){
        homelist hmlist = new homelist();
        JSONObject c = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

        hmlist.setTitle(c.getString("title"));
        hmlist.setPictures(c.getString("picture"));
        hmlist.setHref(c.getString("href"));
        hmlist.setDate(c.getString("date"));

        homelist.add(hmlist);
```

Так вот он парсит массив вида:

```
[{"":"","":""}]
```

Вопрос в следующем: как распарсить такую строку

```
{"":"","":""}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{"":"","":""}` - это объект, а не строка. Если по простому, то хеш-таблица. Парсить её надо соответствующе.

Скажем у вас:

```
JSONObject objJSON;  // там у вас {"":"","":"",...}
```

Если вы знаете все ключи, то по ним и берёте:

```
String val = objJSON.getString("my_key");
```

Если нет, то:

```
// здесь будут все данные
HashMap<String, String> res = new HashMap<String, String>();
//получаем итератор
Iterator itr = objJSON.keys();
//прогоняем
while(itr.hasNext()) {
   String key = itr.next().toString();
   //записываем по ключику значение
   res.put(key, objJSON.get(key));
}
```

Comment: всеравно понять не могу! помогите пожалуйста вот конкретно с этим объектом

{
   "key4": "value4",
   "key3": "value3",
   "key2": "value2",
   "key1": "value1"
}

Comment: @Alerx если мой код используете, то у вас в хеш-таблице res в итоге все эти данные будут.

Comment: спасибо большое) ну что то вроде получилось, но пока вывел в консоль... вывести в ListView не получается и брать данные с http тоже. Что бы я Вас не напрягал, не подскажите какой нибудь исходничек по это теме, где можно разобраться с этим?

Comment: @Alerx я из своих проектов примеры беру, нет сейчас времени статьи искать )

Comment: ааа... ну ладно. большое спасибо

Comment: все, сам разобрался =) большое спасибо за толчек =))

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой пример JSON:

```
[
   {
      "news":{
         "title":"5th title",
         "content":"5th content",
         "date":"1363197493"
      }
   },
   {
      "news":{
         "title":"4th title",
         "content":"4th content",
         "date":"1363197454"
      }
   },
   {
      "news":{
         "title":"3rd title",
         "content":"3rd content",
         "date":"1363197443"
      }
   }
]
```

Парсите так:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);

for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject innerObject = obj.getJSONObject("news");

    String title = innerObject.getString("title");
    String content = innerObject.getString("content");
    String date = innerObject.getString("date");

}
```

Comment: Немного не тот вид.   
У меня так:

    {
       "key4": "value4",
       "key3": "value3",
       "key2": "value2",
      "key1": "value1"
    }